# Controller runs multiple time on click of item in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

In web app i am showing list of items using `ng-repeat` directive of angularjs. And on-click of each item am assigning a summary controller to the summary page (using ui-routing) and shows the result. Currently what happens if there is 10 list items showed using ng-repeat then 10 times summary controller is getting initialized on click of one item. Eventually which makes my app bit slow. Here is my ng-repeat code in html.

```
<div class="surveyList" ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys | filter:headerObj.search track by $index">
    <span class="surveycheckbox" ng-click="toggleClass($event)"></span>
    <div class="toogleSurvey row" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" ng-click="surveyIdForQuota(survey.SurveyID)">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2  col-md-4 surveyitleElipse">{{survey.SurveyName}}</div>                               
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2  col-md-1">
        <span class="title_thumb">
           <span class='fa fa-mobile-phone' ng-show="survey.Type=='App'" title="APP"  my-Tooltip />
          <span class='fa fa-envelope-o' ng-show="survey.Type=='SMS'" title="SMS"  my-Tooltip />
          <span class='fa fa-desktop' ng-show="survey.Type=='Web'"  title="WEB" my-Tooltip/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-2 hidden-xs">{{survey.Date | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2 hidden-xs SurveyLastChild">124</div> 
    <div class="hidden-xs surveyListTool"  ng-show="hoverEdit">
        <a class="editSurvey" title="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2"></i></a>
        <a class="deleteSurvey" ng-click="sendsurveyID(survey.SurveyID)" data-surveyID="{{survey.SurveyID}}" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2"></i></a>
        <a class="cloneSurvey" ng-click="cloneSurvey(survey.SurveyID)" title="clone"><i class="fa fa-clone fa-2"></i></a>
        <a class="menuSurvey" title="menu">
             <i class="fa fa-circle fa-2"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-circle fa-2"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-circle fa-2"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- On click Of the list am showing this div box -->
    <div class="surveyDetailsBox"> <!--This is the header section -->
        <div class="surveyDetailHead">
              <p class="surveyTitle">{{survey.SurveyName}}</p>
              <div class="surveyDetailHeadTool" >
                   <a class="editSurvey" title="edit" ng-click="showEditSurveyForm(survey.SurveyID,$index);"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2"></i></a>
                   <a class="deleteSurvey hidden-xs" ng-click="sendsurveyID(survey.SurveyID)" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2"></i></a>
                   <a class="menuSurvey"  title="menu">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-2"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-2"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-2"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="hidden-xs"  title="close"><i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-2"></i></a>
               </div>
        </div>
        <!--This is the body section where summary and other modules are present -->
        <div class="surveyDetailContent hidden-xs" ng-if="is_desktop">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 leftMenu">
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList.details" class="list-group-item summary" ui-sref-active="active">Summary</a>
                            <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList.questionare" class="list-group-item "  ui-sref-active="active">Questionaire Management</a>
                            <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList.sampleManagement" class="list-group-item "  ui-sref-active="active">Sample Management</a>
                            <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList.quotaManagement" class="list-group-item "  ui-sref-active="active">Quota Management</a>
                            <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList.scheduling" class="list-group-item "  ui-sref-active="active">Scheduling</a>
                            <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList.notification" class="list-group-item "  ui-sref-active="active">Notifications</a>
                            <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList.reports" class="list-group-item "  ui-sref-active="active">Reports</a>
                            <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList.location" class="list-group-item "  ui-sref-active="active">Geolocation</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 rightContent" ui-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For each sub module like Summary, questionnare etc., one controller is associated.

On click of this list am showing the summary box and running the controller also.

Code for `surveyIdForQuota()` goes here

```
$scope.surveyIdForQuota = function(SurveyID){
    $rootScope.quotaSurveyID = SurveyID;
    $scope.exportViewDetails="";
      $http.get(__env.apiUrl+"/UserSurvey/GetInvitationCount?surveyId="+$rootScope.surveysummaryID,{headers:{"Content-type":"application/json",'sessionID':$rootScope.token}}).
        then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
          $scope.summaryDetails = response.data;
      },function(error){console.log(error)})
  };
```

Comment: show the code for `surveyIdForQuota()`

Comment: Added the code for surveyIdForQuota()

Comment: Share your `div` tag full code

Comment: I will give complete html code...

Answer (score 0):

> `ng-click` should be add on the item of list

```
<div class="surveyList" ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys |filter:headerObj.search track by survey.SurveyID"> <div ng-
click="surveyIdForQuota(survey.SurveyID)">)">//rest code inside goes here</div></div>
```

Your first div is a parent div, but you wrote `ng-click` on the list. So if you click any place of the div. it will be call the method

Comment: doesn't explain why? Curious what the reason is myself

Comment: What happening if you try this? and please share your full div code.

Comment: I added the complete html, Can you check now ?